# Adding convex hull to ggplot map

Tags: r

I am trying to create a ggplot that includes coordinates, density, and a convex hull polygon.

The data is a set of twenty latitudinal and longitudinal points.

This is my code:

```html
# Data

economy <- read.csv("data-economy.csv", header=TRUE)

# Convex hulls.

hulls <- ddply(economy, .(Latitude, Longitude), function(economy) 
            economy[chull(economy$Latitude, economy$Longitude), ])

fig <- ggplot(economy, aes(Latitude, Longitude, colour="black", fill="black")) + 
              geom_point() + 
              geom_density2d(alpha=.5) + 
              labs(x = "Latitude", y = "Longitude") + 
              geom_polygon(data=hulls, alpha=.2)

fig
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: economypolygon1]

I've tried a few things, and I can't get the convex hull to include only the points with max latitude and longitude. I can get the shape that I want outside of ggplot by using this code:

```html
X <- economy
chull(X)
plot(X, cex = 0.5)
hpts <- chull(X)
hpts <- c(hpts, hpts[1])
lines(X[hpts, ])
```

The result that it gives me is this:

[image: economypolygon2]

How can I get the same shape as in R base in ggplot?

Also, why when I change the color in my ggplot code, does it not change the plot?

Comment: See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22805/how-to-draw-neat-polygons-around-scatterplot-regions-in-ggplot2

Comment: @Mikko Marttila Thanks. I used the code from that question to come up with what I have so far. I'm not seeing why it's not using only the outside points from my data - any ideas?

Comment: In your `ddply` call you are splitting your data by unique values of `Latitude` and `Longitude` (i.e. distinct points) and finding the convex hull for each point, which is just the point itself.

Comment: Try just doing `hulls <- economy[chull(economy$Latitude, economy$Longitude), ]`

Comment: The answer in the linked Cross Validated post uses `ddply` in order to find a convex hull for multiple groups at the same time; while in your problem you just have one set of points to find a solution for, so you don't need `ddply` here.

Answer (score 29):

Your problem is with the `ddply`: currently your code splits the data by distinct values of `Latitude` and `Longitude` (i.e. each point you're plotting), finds the convex hull in each split (which is just the point itself) and binds the results together, effectively just giving you a row for each point in your data. That's why the polygon you draw touches every point.

Here's a solution that should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Find the convex hull of the points being plotted
hull <- mtcars %>%
  slice(chull(mpg, wt))

# Define the scatterplot
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(shape = 21)

# Overlay the convex hull
p + geom_polygon(data = hull, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Now if you wanted to add a grouping to your plot, all you need to do is calculate the `chull` for each level of your grouping variable:

```r
# Calculate the hulls for each group
hull_cyl <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  slice(chull(mpg, wt))

# Update the plot with a fill group, and overlay the new hulls
p + aes(fill = factor(cyl)) + geom_polygon(data = hull_cyl, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

By the way, there's also a nice example in one of the `ggplot2` vignettes, where they go through a step-by-step guide to creating custom stats and geoms, using the convex hull as an example: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html.

Comment: I came here to admire the `slice(chull())`. Elegant, nice!